# How to refresh a TreeItem's nodes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TreeView that displays a list of servers and a list of databases under each server, so it looks something like this:

```
-localhost
---database1
---database2
---database3
-remotehost
---database4
---database5
---database6
```

The databases in each server are not populated until the treeitem of that server is selected(to save load time). Now, when a different server becomes selected, I want to refresh the list of databases on that newly selected server. Currently, my script only adds the list of dbs to the newly selected server but doesn't remove the dbs that were already there, even though I have the script to remove them in place.  What am I doing wrong?

```
connTree.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void changed(
        ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> observable,
        TreeItem<String> old_val, TreeItem<String> new_val) {
        TreeItem<String> selectedItem = new_val;
        String selectedHost = selectedItem.getValue();
        if (selectedHost != "test") {
            if (conns.exists(selectedHost)) {
                selectedServer = conns.get(selectedHost);
                selectedServer.getDatabases();
                List<String> dbs = selectedServer.databases;
                TreeItem<String> c = connTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                c.getChildren().removeAll(c); //This should do what I want, right?
                for (String db: dbs) {
                    Button dbIcon = new Button("", new Glyph("FontAwesome", "DATABASE"));
                    dbIcon.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                    TreeItem<String> branch = new TreeItem<String>(db, dbIcon);
                    branch.setExpanded(true);
                    selectedItem.getChildren().add(branch);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
});
```

I dont get any errors. The nodes are just never removed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to print the result of the `removeAll(c)` and if its false then try to search if the TreeItem actually contains the 'c' if again it doesn't loop through all Strings inside the TreeItem and see what is wrong. Those debugging tips may help you out.

Comment: `//This should do what I want, right?` most certainly not. Assuming you didn't add a circular relationship in the tree(which probably is prevented) it's effectively a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, `selectedItem.getChildren().clear()` did the trick. I'm not sure what the difference between clear() and removeAll() is, but clear() works.

Comment: [`ObservableList.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#removeAll-E...-) removes all elements from the list that you pass as paramers to the method. If you only pass elements to the method that are not in the list, the list is not modified at all...  In the code in your question it's equivalent to `c.getChildren().remove(c);`.